# How to determine which property to set or method to call after Enum.TryParse(PropertyName, out Property)

Tags: c#, reflection, dictionary, properties, enums

I have a Dictionary where the key is a string representing the name of a property on a class and the value is the value I want to assign to the property. I have determined what property the Dictionary item is referencing, but I am unsure of how to actually set that property or call an appropriate method without using a ridiculous switch statement with all the possible properties. Is there some efficient way to do this? I cannot alter the UserConfiguration class or extend it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> PDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"UserName", "Steve"},
            {"Location", "Over There Somewhere"},
            {"Color", "Mellow Yellow"},
            {"Password", "ILikeCheese"}
        };

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        foreach (var prop in PDictionary)
        {
            UserConfiguration.Property property;
            Enum.TryParse(prop.Key, out property);

            //Set appropriate property or call appropriate method...

        }
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration
{
    public enum Property
    {
        UserName,
        Location,
        Color,
        Password
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public void SetPassword(string password)
    {
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

Anybody have any good ideas?

Comment: I think, as general solution, you can do it using reflection only.

Comment: `UserConfiguration` class can change, adding or removing properties, in the future?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria, yes, it can change in the future, but I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a method in `Class1` that has a paremeter `enum Property` that sets the correct properties, you can **use reflection** like this (sorry for any compilation errors I dont have acess to VS right now)

```
Type tClass ;
Type paramType ;
MethodInfo[] methods ;
ParameterInfo[] params ;
Class1 c1 ;
UserConfiguration.Property property;

Enum.TryParse(prop.Key, out property);

Object []paramValues = {prop.value} ;

tClass = typeof(Class1) ;


c1 = new Class1() ;

bool invoked ;

invoked = false ;

//get all the methods of your Class1
methods = tClass.GetMethods() ;

foreach(MethodInfo mi in methods)
{
    //get the parameters of the current method
    params = mi.GetParameters() ;
    if(params != null)
    {
        foreach(ParameterInfo pi in params)
        {
            paramType = pi.ParameterType ;

            if(paramType = typeof(UserConfiguration.Property))
            {
                //a method that receives a userconfiguration properpty has been found
                //now you can call it
                mi.Invoke(c1, paramValues) ;
                invoked = true ;
                break ;
            }
        }
    }
    if(invoked)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you have methods with names like `setUserName`, `setLocation`, `setColor` and `setPassword` then you can do something like this

```
Type tClass ;
Type paramType ;
MethodInfo[] methods ;
ParameterInfo[] params ;
Class1 c1 ;
UserConfiguration.Property property;

Enum.TryParse(prop.Key, out property);

Object []paramValues = {prop.Value} ;

tClass = typeof(Class1) ;


c1 = new Class1() ;

bool invoked ;

invoked = false ;

//get all the methods of your Class1

methods = tClass.GetMethods() ;
foreach(MethodInfo mi in methods)
{
    if(mi.Name.StartsWith("set" + prop.Key)
    {
        //a method name "set<PropertyName>" has been found
        //now you can call it
        mi.Invoke(c1, paramValues) ;
        break ;
    }
}
```

I suggest that you take a look at the Type class to decide which approch is better for you

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.type.aspx**

Comment: I've determined I have to use reflection. Now I just need to study up on what reflection is. (Kinda noobish over here.)

Comment: Actually, the methods that set the properties take only strings. I might have to use a switch or some loop for determining which methods to call. :(

Comment: @BoilerBrad i have added another example of reflection that calls method like "setLocation" or "setColor" depending on the property name

Answer (score 2):

Put this into your class:

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        Type myType = typeof(UserConfiguration);
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
    }
    set
    {
        Type myType = typeof(UserConfiguration);
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

Then you can get/set properties within the class using `myClassInstance[property] = myValue;`

Comment: Which class? I cannot alter the UserConfiguration Class.

Comment: @BoilerBrad - Put it into your solution in a class.  It's just an extension method for Object.  If you wanted you could use <T> and use typeof(T) to make it generic.  For now, just put it in the class where you are trying to set the property.

Comment: You should put it in Class1.  But I see you've already accepted an answer.  This does work, and it's a fairly generic solution which you could use all over your solution.  Maybe it'll help someone else :)

Comment: I found my error! I did not have the accessors defined on my properties. DOH! I'll give you some up-votes for good measure :P

Comment: @BoilerBrad - lol, thanks... I prefer my way to your accepted answers way as my way is cleaner, doesn't require loops and can easily be abstracted away without worry.  Thanks again for posting back that you fixed your issue, people may have been put off using this method otherwise! :D

Comment: @Vijay I also like your way better ;-) I just did not now about this technique

Comment: @MauricioGracia - Thanks, it's not often you get someone with an accepted answer saying they appreciate someone elses' answer :)